# I want to get a router params in Vue Component before it created

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I develop a ecommerce website with Vue.js2,

for the single product page, I have a route like

```
  {
    path: '/product/:code',
    name: 'product',
    props:true,
    component: Product
  },
```

And in the component I have somthing like

```
props: {
  code: {
    type:String
  }
},
data: ()=> {
  return {
    product:{}
  }
},
beforeMount(){
  axios
  .get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/'+this.code)
  .then((response) => {
     this.plan = response.data,
     this.ListImages = response.data.ListImages;
     console.log(this.ListImages)
     console.log(this.plan)
   })
 }
```

The data is retrieved but the component is already create but if I do the request "beforeCreate()" the "this.code" is "undefined" and when I use "$router.params.code" an error is occured stating that "$router" is not the define.

Please can I have some help?

Comment: Just a friendly advice: fetch should be performed in the created() hook as per vue js docs. If something goes wrong in beforeMount() hook you probably will have a non-mounted component and a bad user experience. IMO, you should do the fetch in created() hook and show some spinner while loading data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use it like this:

```
this.$route.params.code
```